# Plotting multiple datasets in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have voltage and current signals from multiple days. The time vector is in seconds of the day (SOD), and the voltage and current vectors are in volts and amps respectively. However, the vector data from each day is different lengths. For example Mondays data might be 1x100000 for both time and voltage/current, and Tuesdays might be 1x50000 for both time and voltage/current. I was asked to plot the different days of data on the same figure for comparison purposes. I have tried using the `plot(x1,y1,x2,y2)` method but that obviously didn't work due to different vector lengths. I tried interpolating to the larger data set, but then realized that I will get all `NaNs` on the result since there is no overlap in time. I ran out of ideas and am desperately in need of help.

**EDIT:**
I guess I forgot to mention that somehow I would like to overlay them one on top of the other in the same figure and not using a subplot.

Comment: "that obviously didn't work due to different vector lengths"; really?  If `x1` and `y1` are both from the same day, they should have the same number of elements of time and voltage/current.  Only that element count needs to match.  The element count of (`x2`,`y2`) doesn't matter to the (`x1`,`y1`) pair.

Comment: Let me correct myself. It worked, however, the data was not lined up. The latter day data was obviously shifted more towards the right. What I'd like to do is align them...

Comment: Gotcha.  Does a linear shift to `0` for both `x`-data suffice?  Namely, `plot(x1 - x1(1),y1,x2 - x2(1),y2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a data vector of length `n` to span, I'm guessing, 24 hours = 86400 seconds, for any `n` (e.g. `n=100000` or `n=50000`). Assuming the original data is uniformly sampled, this should do the trick:

```
x1=linspace(0,86400,length(x1));
x2=linspace(0,86400,length(x2));
plot(x1,y1,'r-',x2,y2,'b-');
```

If it is not uniformly sampled, we can still make it work:

```
t1=linspace(0,86400,length(x1));
t2=linspace(0,86400,length(x2));
newy1 = spline(x1,y1,t1);
newy2 = spline(x2,y2,t2);
plot(t1,newy1,'r-',t2,newy2,'b-');
```